# What's this font?

Tags: fonts

[image]

What's this font? And how can I add package for this?

Comment: Welcome! Did you look in the PDF properties?

Comment: My guess is URW Palladio (`\usepackage{mathpazo}`), cf. [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zI5sl.png).

Answer (score 2):

For me, this font looks like TeX Gyre Pagella ( `\usepackage{tgpagella}` ).
Just to be sure, check the properties of the PDF file to see which fonts are used.
[image: Tex Gyre Pagella]

Comment: You should show a typeset example to provide a visual comparison.